# How to show byte[] as img

Tags: javascript, json, gson

I got java webapp using GSON. There GSON puts image from db into json. It looks like that:

`"image":{"buf":[00,00...],"pos":50,"mark":50,"count":163790}`

I`m trying to show it as image with something like that

`$("#question_image").attr("src","data:image/jpeg;base64," + image.buf);`

But it does not work. I do not know why.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to convert it to Base64.

Comment: Couldnt you render it on a canvas?